# How to make clones of a panel with controls in it programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Right, I'm losing my mind at this point. But as the title suggests, I want to make copies of a panel (n) amount of times via code but I cant figure it out. The `Panel` itself has a `Label`, a `TextBox` and a `Button` (it doesn't necessarily have to be in a panel). Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Look at code generated by designer and copy it

Comment: I think you want a user-control. This (rather old) article explains it very well: https://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_user_controls.html

Comment: Create a `UserControl`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  made a usercontrol and it works just as i wanted it to. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a UserControl with the controls i needed and it works just as i wanted it to, can instantiate it as many times as i want. Thanks guys.